# How to ask "How do I spell x?"

Tags: перевод

я совсем не знаю как я изучаю более чем год, без знании как спросить "How do you spell that?" в моём словарнный запас.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is written in very wrong language and totally wrong cases and endings. What the Russian part of the question says is totally unclear. You should ask in English, I think.

Answer (score 7):

When you say "how do you spell it(that)?", you expect the person to name each letter separately in order to write it down. Unfortunately, we don't have the verb with the same meaning. You can either ask "how do you write that" (**как это пишется?**), because your purpose is to write it down, but if you don't achieve your goal, just add, "**по буквам, пожалуйста**".

Answer (score 4):

You should use "Как пишется слово Х" to know how to write the word.

If you are not sure how to read the word - ask "как произносится это слово".

Answer (score 1):

I assume, by "spell" you mean 'to write correctly'. You say that as

> "Как [правильно] пишется X?" (lit. 'How [correctly] is written X?')

or

> "Как [правильно] написать X?" (lit. 'How [correctly] to write X?')